# In what points is this function total differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: (x,y) \mapsto x\sin (|y|)$. In what points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is this function total derivable? Prove carefully.

Just by computation, I found that the total derivative is $d(f(x,y)) = \sin(|y|)dx + x\cos(|y|)\frac{y}{|y|}dy$ for all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ except those where $y=0$.

I have some difficulty proving that this is true.

This was one of the problems on last year's midterm.

Comment: Your total derivative is correct. Now the question is to look at whether $f$ is differentiable on the points of the line $y=0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Would it suffice to show that the partial derivative with respect to $y$ doesn't exist for $y=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation of the total derivative is correct for $y \neq 0$. And $f$ is indeed differentiable for $y \neq 0$.

At $(0,0)$ $f$ is also differentiable as you have the inequalities

$$\vert f(x,y) \vert \le \vert xy \vert \le \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$$ proving that the total derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is the always vanishing linear map.

Now, if $f$ was differentiable at $(x,0)$ with $x \neq 0$, $g(x,y) = \sin \vert y \vert$ would also be as the ratio of two differentiable maps at a point is differentiable if the denominator doesn't vanish at that point.

It is then easy to conclude... as the map $(x,y) \mapsto \sin \vert y \vert$ is not differentiable at $y =0$.

Conclusion: $f$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$ if and only if $(x,y) \notin D= \{(u,v) \mid u \neq 0 \text{ and } v=0\}$.